# What are some good Javascript front end (web page) faceted search libraries as alternatives to filtrify?

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have a website that uses filtrify to provide faceted searching through a very long, involved list.  This is working great and is a fantastic web-based, front-end only, Javascript project that takes my list and creates the roll ups, does the counting, etc for me.  It really is awesome.

But it has not been updated since 2014 and is not 508 compliant, which is my new requirement.

I need something that:

- Embed on existing webpages
- Does not do a round-trip ( I don't have the ability to do a behind the scenes solr or Elasticsearch or Splunk or whatever)
- Preferably pure javascript
- Does faceted searches
- Is 508 compliant or I can manipulate it (which Javascript would allow me to do)

So, I have a list of objects with properties:

```
Foo - is a -> Bar
Foo - is a -> Baz
Foo - has a -> chocolate
Foo - is a type of -> Var
Foo - ranked as -> Awesome
```

And I need to give my users the ability to look for all the objects that have "chocolate" or an "Awesome" rank.

I'm running out of ideas on how to search for this.